# Resharper IntelliSense suggests any short string being typed as a class name

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, intellisense, resharper-8.2

I have a problem with my IntelliSense (Visual Studio 2010 using Resharper 8.2.1)

Note: I have elected to switch IntelliSense for "Letter and digits" to "Display but do not preselect" to not be bothered too much.

It has the stupid idea that everything I write is a new class:

```
foreach (var dataGridViewRow in regning.Value)
{
    var rykker = dataGridViewRow.Tag as Rykker;
    if (rykker != null)
    {
        sum += rykker.Beloeb + rykker.RykkerBeloeb + rykker.RenteBeloeb + ry|;
    }
}
```

[image: Also it does it where no class name is expected]
.

Suggestions are:

- Class "ry" (does not exist and is not wanted)
- Variable "rykker" (what I am most likely to want)
- Class "Rykker"
- Other things with "ry" in them

It also makes making an if statement somewhat annoying as it will substitute "if" for "@if" in order to have "if" be the name of a class

The problem goes away when I type the third letter, but at one letter it will suggest all two-character combinations starting with the letter:

[image]

I would like it to NOT suggest classes the do not exist - how can I do this?

Comment: Please select "ry" class and then apply 'ReSharper | Navigate | Go to Declaration' on it. It should open the class declaration. I can't believe R# IntelliSense may show non-existent entities.

Comment: @Alexander I just tried that, and the "Go to Delclaration" is grayed out in the menu along with "Go to Implementation" =0( The Odd thing is then, that there is no indication of the class NOT existing - it even compiles! This is the case with every two-character name I've tried. The moment I reach three characters it stops thinking it a class name.